# Establish communication between React web server running on AWS and Flask app running on Raspberry Pi 4 Model B

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, raspberry-pi

I am working prototype of a React based webpage running on AWS server that has a feature that lets the UI running from any browser on any particular PC to send HTTP requests to control a local network Raspberry Pi 4 Model B, which runs a Flask app to process those commands. This Raspberry Pi is connected to the same WLAN as the previously mentioned PC and accessed through localhost:8081 port. Ideally, we would be able to communicate locally between the React Webpage and Raspberry PI over local router, but we face issues where we don't have admin rights issues at certain work environments which makes it less scalable. To bypass this issue, I have a ngrok setup that enables me to access this localhost:8081 port remotely, essentially enabling me to control the Rpi over the internet. However, I am facing issues with this setup as well because of connection stability over NGROK server in certain regions. The goal is to replace ngrok server as well as localhost:8081 port access by establishing direct connection between the React Webpage server and the Flask app running on the Raspberry Pi over the internet. I would love to hear any suggestions to implement this!

My current idea is using socketIO on both sides to establish communication between the app and the server, but I'm not sure if this is the right move